# Remove the colored box on hover for single points and show when multiple points are intersecting Chart Js

Tags: canvas, charts, chart.js, tooltip

I am looking to have it function similar to this [[multiple points]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocPDm.png)[Single Point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF9IM.png)
Basically the colored boxes will only show if there are points overlapping and need to be differentiated based on the line. Any ideas?

```
tooltips: {

    enabled: true,
    mode: 'point',
    displayColors: true,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 252, 252, 1)',
    bodyFontColor: 'rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)',
    cornerRadius: 2,
    xPadding: 10,
    yPadding: 12,
    caretSize: 10,
    callbacks: {
      title: () => null,
      label: t => t.yLabel.toLocaleString() + ' kBtu/GSF',
      afterLabel: (t, d) => (typeof footnotes[d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label] !== 'undefined' && typeof footnotes[d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label][t.xLabel] === 'string')
        ? footnotes[d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label][t.xLabel].replace(/\n\s+/g, '\n')
        : null
    }
  },
  // Note: set this on the global variable
  hover: {
    mode: 'point',
    onHover: 
  }
```